# Compact hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

I want to show that for some compact hypersurface $M$ in $\mathbb{R}$ it holds that for any $v \in S^n$ there exists some $p \in M$, s.t. $v$ is the unit normal to $T_pM$. I also have the hint to look at the hyperplanes $Rv+v^{\perp}$ for some $R>0$, s.t. this hyperplane and $M$ are disjoint and then to look at the point with minimal distance to $Rv+v^{\perp}$.

Now I can picture this (for $n \leq 3$ obviously) because then $Rv+v^{\perp}$ is some plane $\cong \mathbb{R}^2$ and if I take the point with minimal distance its obvious (graphically) that its tangent space has to be orthogonal to $v$. But I don't know how to formalize this.

I can get the point with minimal distance to $Rv+v^{\perp}$ by looking at the smooth function $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, q \mapsto dist(q,Rv+v^{\perp})$ which has a minimum since $M$ is compact.

Can somebody give me some hint how to formalize this (for all dimensions)?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, my problem is that I can't formulate an answer to this, the first answer in this question is also just an idea of proof as similar to mine but it doesn't answer my question

Comment: unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be a unit vector. Consider the map $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x \cdot v$.

Then, at any $x \in M$, $d_x f: X \in T_xM \subset \mathbb{R}^n \longmapsto v \cdot X$. There exists some $x \in M$ at which $f$ is maximal.

Then $d_xf=0$, thus $T_xM \subset v^{\perp}$, hence $T_xM=v^{\perp}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I still don't understand is, why does $d_xf$ look this way? I know the definitions for the differential of a function between two manifolds but I sometimes don't know how to apply it to such "simple" manifolds as the $\mathbb{R}^n$.. From the definition I know, it would be: $d_xf:T_xM \rightarrow T_{x \cdot v}\mathbb{R}, w \mapsto (g \mapsto w(g \circ f))$. Now choose $g=identity$ and $x$ s.t. $f$ is maximal in $x$. Then $0=w(f)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n w_i \partial_i f=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n  w_i v_i $ and therefore $<w,v>=0$ for all $w \in T_pM$

Comment: Is that correct? How do you get $d_xf$ in the form yo've written down? And why do we know that $v^{\perp} \subset T_xM$?

Comment: For the second part, look at the dimensions. For the first part, you can check it using the definition of the tangent space with paths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variational approach which (for $N$ a proposed hyperplane) follows the hint:

> Assume  $M$, $N$ are submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$ and there are points $p\in M$, $q\in N$ such that $d(p,q)=\inf_{m\in M,n\in N} d(m,n)>0$. Set $v=p-q$. Then $v\perp T_pM$ and $v\perp T_qN$.

$\textbf{proof:}$

Let $w\in T_pM$ and choose a curve $\gamma: (\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$ with $\gamma(0)=p$, $\gamma'(0)=w$ and define $\delta (t)=d(\gamma(t),q)^2$. Then as $\delta$ achieves a minimum at $0$:

$$0=\delta'(0)=\langle \gamma(t)-q,\gamma(t)-q\rangle'(0)
=2\cdot \langle\gamma'(0),\gamma(0)-q\rangle=2\langle w,v\rangle$$
Hence $v\perp T_pM$ and then  by  symmetry also $v\perp T_qN$.